# Tell if shift is being held in onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to fire an onClick only if `meta`(mac) / `ctrl`(win) is being held when it's clicked.

Here's what I tried:

```
const [shiftOn, setShiftOn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.code === 'KeyC') {
        setShiftOn(true)
      }
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.code === 'KeyC') {
        setShiftOn(false)
      }
    })
  })

  const highlightCol = () => {
    console.log(shiftOn) // always false
    if (shiftOn) ... do something
  }

const col = (
        <td onClick={highlightCol} {...tdProps}>
          {colName}
        </td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there -- `metaKey`, `shiftKey`, etc are what you're looking for -- but you're looking for them in the wrong place: those will simply be boolean properties on the click event itself. You do *not* need to check for separate keydown or keyup events on the shift or cmd keys, so can delete everything you have in a useEffect.

All you need is the single click handler:

```
  const highlightCol = e => {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
      // shift key was down during the click
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      // ctrl key was down during the click 
    }
  }
```

The onClick will always be fired; just check its event's shiftKey (or metaKey or altKey or ctrlKey) properties to decide whether to do anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

Different browser can have different implementations of detecting pressed keys.
I think the problem here is that you detect ctrl/meta key incorrectly.

Try to look into this service to find out what ways you have to detect particular key.

Below is what it shows for me when I press ctrl key on win.

[image]

It is better to use several methods of detecting keys to cover all browsers and platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrong in the way detect control key. By the way, just register event listener 1 time.

```
const Component =(props)=>{
    const [valueFromChild, setValueFromChild] = useState('');

    const [shiftOn, setShiftOn] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            console.log('dow', e);
            e.preventDefault()
            if (e.key === 'Control') {
                setShiftOn(true)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            console.log('up', e);
            e.preventDefault()
            if (e.key === 'Control') {
                setShiftOn(false)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    const highlightCol = () => {
        console.log(shiftOn) // always false
        if (shiftOn) {

        }
    }

    return <>
        {shiftOn ? 'on' : 'off'}
        <button onClick={highlightCol} > Click </button>
        </>
}
```